# Django one time initializer

Tags: python, django, class, client-server

Is it possible to make one time initializer?
I have some python code, and want to initialize it one time after Django's  server is up. 
And after requesting some page class variable of that code will be used.
Is it possible to make that?
Please don’t be harsh on me. I’m new in Django and python

Comment: Django is not server. Its framework. I had same question when I was learning.

Comment: I meant the Django’s default server

Comment: Check these links: [Install django on your server](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html), [Setup Django](https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281)